# Port 80 closed on RHat enterprise server 7.7 EC2 image all of a sudden

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redhat, spotfire

one of our EC2 instances got broken all of a sudden and we couldn't reach it. It's running a [Spotfire Server](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire_server/7.11.6/doc/html/TIB_sfire_server_tsas_admin_help/GUID-C1E440AE-94EB-4E6E-BBB5-F3D556934D82.html) (i.e. Tomcat web app). I ran `nmap -Rn- <IP-address>` I found out that the only open port is `22`. Port `80` is closed and I don't know why it got closed all of a sudden.

What would be the best way to get that port opened? I searched online and people seem to suggest installing `firewall-cmd` (it's not installed at the moment) but I am wondering if that is a good idea as, after all, we have "Security Groups" on AWS which serves as a firewall.

What would be the best way to re-open port 80?

Note: I checked the security groups for the EC2 instance and according to it the port should be open:

[image]

Comment: If this happens to single instance, and other instances in same subnet and VPC are fine, then problem is in instance. Make sure server actually runs and listens to port 80, because at first glance it looks like dead server process.

Comment: As Oleksii says, this is more likely due to no service listening on port 80, rather than the port actually being blocked. Depending on your server config, Nmap can't tell the difference between a blocked port, and a port that is simply passive (no responding). I would focussing on whether your web container is running correctly.

Comment: Thank you both! I checked and you both were right, there is nothing that is listening on that port and that's why nmap is reporting it as closed. Thank you very much! I will try restarting the app and hopefully that fixes it